# How to convert stream to file and send it for download in python

Tags: python

I am writing an application where receive file like a stream like this:

```
zipfile = subprocess.Popen(somearguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=in_stream, close_fds=True)

return  zipfile.stdout.read()
```

How I can convert this stream to zip file, and send it to browser to download? I have read a lot of articles, but I am new in python and do not know what will be the best solution.  If file is correct I will display download link:

```
<a href=”test.py”> "Click for download" </a>
```

which will redirect to test.py script.

where test.py has to receive this zip file and send it to browser for download.  I have read about context-disposition and how it should be used in such cases but still do not have solution.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: When are you doing the `subprocess` call? Is this something that would be done ahead of time, or only when the file is requested by a web client? Are you using any web framework yet?

Comment: Subprocess call is invoked in every 3 minutes. It executes back end command which returns zip file as a stream. However for me it is not so important, how to convert this stream to file, but how to send this file to test.py script and make it downloadable through browser.

Comment: What is it exactly you want to know? How to tell the script which file to compress? How to compress it?
Side note: Are you using a web framework for this? Like Django? (in that case the link would look totally different)

Comment: I want to know how user will be able to click on lnik "Download" and this will open new window where file will start to download. Sorry if I do not express myself clear enough. I do not use Django, for client side only html, css ... back end - python.

Comment: If your web site is pure HTML/CSS, it might make sense to just write the zip-file data to a regular file somewhere your web server can see it. Then you don't need a special Python script to serve it up, just have the web page point directly at the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339745/how-to-deploy-zip-files-or-other-binaries-trough-cgi-in-python  this is what I am looking for. I will try with this approach to send the file to browser for download. Thank you for your comments. I will update my post when I find a proper solution based on your advices.